# How to apply constness from templated type to another type

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make a reference to a value that's inside a templated class. The templated class can be const or non-const so the value reference needs to reflect that. In f(), how do you apply the constness from T to the value_ref declaration?

```
class X
{
public:
    typedef int value_type;
    value_type v;
};

template<typename T>
void f(T & x) {
    // needs constness of T applied to T::value_type
    typedef typename T::value_type & value_ref;
    auto lambda = [](value_ref v){};  // can't use auto in MSVC2010
    lambda(x.v);
}

void g() {
    X x;

    X & r = x;
    f(r);       // works

    X const & cr = x;
    f(cr);     // error: cannot convert from 'const X::value_type' to 'value_type &'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11 this is fairly simple with `std::remove_const`:

```
template<class T, class U>
struct transfer_const { using type = typename std::remove_const<U>::type; };

template<class T, class U>
struct transfer_const<const T, U> { using type = const U; };
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. That makes perfect sense. I know I've seen kind of thing before but I can't seem to remember these techniques, in this case using a template class to generate another type.

Answer (score 2):

What about using auto?

```
template<typename T>
void f(T & x) {
    auto &r = x.v;
}
```

Comment: Good catch. My example is not complete. I actually need to use the type for a lambda declaration (no lambda autos in VC++2010). I'll update the example in 30secs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper class to deduce whether the `value_type` needs to be `int&` or `const int&`.

```
class X
{
   public:
      typedef int value_type;
      value_type v;
};

template <typename T> struct reference_type;

template <> struct reference_type<X>
{
   using type = int&;
};

template <> struct reference_type<const X>
{
   using type = int const&;
};


template <typename T>
void f(T & x) {
   // needs constness of T applied to T::value_type
   typedef typename reference_type<T>::type value_ref;
   value_ref vr = x.v;
}

void g() {
   X x;

   X & r = x;
   f(r);       // works

   X const & cr = x;
   f(cr);     // error: cannot convert from 'const X::value_type' to 'value_type &'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is enough info for me to solve the problem. @orlp gave me the exact thing though so I gave him the point but thank you so much for your helpful response.